# While under the effect of the invisibility spell, would using a wand of pyrotechnics break the invisibility?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, invisibility

The wand of pyrotechnics is a common magic item in Dragon of Icespire Peak.  The text reads as follow:

> This wand has 7 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges and create a harmless burst of multicolored light at a point you can see up to 60 feet away. The burst of light is accompanied by a crackling noise that can be heard up to 300 feet away. The light is as bright as a torch flame but lasts only a second.
>
> The wand regains 1d6 + 1 expended charges daily at dawn. If you expend the wand’s last charge, roll a d20. On a 1, the wand erupts in a harmless pyrotechnic display and is destroyed.

**If a person under the effects of an invisibility spell uses the wand, would it cause the invisibility spell to end?**
My assumption is no because it doesn't count as a spell or an attack.

My follow-up questions is this:
**Can an invisible person use other magic wands or items without ending the invisibility spell, so long as the item does not say it counts as casting spell or the item isn't used to make an attack?**

Answer (score 14):

## *Invisibility* is only broken when **casting a spell** or **making an attack**

*Invisibility* (PHB, p. 254) reads:

> The spell ends for a target that **attacks** or **casts a spell**

It is specific about what events cause it to end. Since the wand of pyrotechnics is not casting a spell nor is it making an attack (no attack roll) it does not break invisibility. This is true for all magic items that do not involve casting a spell or making an attack.

Note that other wands do break invisibility depending on what they do. For example the *Wand of Fireballs* (DMG, p. 210) reads:

> This wand has 7 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 or more of its charges to **cast the fireball spell** (save DC 15) from it.

because using the wand involves casting a spell the effects of *invisibility* are ended.

Answer (score 2):

Odo's answer is fairly straightforward and accurate (+1), but I feel that it is worth noting that invisibility is a concentration spell.

Taking an action that injures you, such as drinking an unidentified potion that was a damaging poison, would cause a concentration check. Taking an action that causes you to become incapacitated, such as if the poison instead petrified you, would cause the spell to end immediately. Be mindful of cursed items in this situation.

This is not restricted to magic items either. Manipulating a trapped chest or door could lead down this path as well.